# Checking contents of char variable - C Programming

Tags: c, variables, if-statement, char

This might seem like a very simple question, but I am struggling with it.  I have been writing iPhone apps with Objective C for a few months now, but decided to learn C Programming to give myself a better grounding.

In Objective-C if I had a UILabel called 'label1' which contained some text, and I wanted to run some instructions based on that text then it might be something like;

```
if (label1.text == @"Hello, World!")
{
NSLog(@"This statement is true");
}
else {
NSLog(@"Uh Oh, an error has occurred");
}
```

I have written a VERY simple C Program I have written which uses `printf()` to ask for some input then uses `scanf()` to accept some input from the user, so something like this;

```
int main()
{
    char[3] decision;

    Printf("Hi, welcome to the introduction program.  Are you ready to answer some questions? (Answer yes or no)");
    scanf("%s", &decision);
}
```

What I wanted to do is apply an `if` statement to say if the user entered yes then continue with more questions, else print out a line of text saying thanks.

After using the scanf() function I am capturing the users input and assigning it to the variable 'decision' so that should now equal yes or no.  So I assumed I could do something like this;

```
if (decision == yes)
{
     printf("Ok, let's continue with the questions");
}
else 
{
     printf("Ok, thank you for your time.  Have a nice day.");
}
```

That brings up an error of "use of undeclared identifier yes".  I have also tried;

```
if (decision == "yes")
```

Which brings up "result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified"

I have tried seeing if it works by counting the number of characters so have put;

```
if (decision > 3)
```

But get "Ordered comparison between pointer and integer 'Char and int'"

And I have also tried this to check the size of the variable, if it is greater than 2 characters it must be a yes;

```
if (sizeof (decision > 2))
```

I appreciate this is probably something simple or trivial I am overlooking but any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: first very beginning error You make, is misuse 'char variable' in topic, and 'string variable' or 'char * variable' or 'char []' in content. For every C programmer char variable is: char c;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daniel Haviv's answer told you what you should do. I wanted to explain why the things you tried didn't work:

```
if (decision == yes)
```

There is no identifier 'yes', so this isn't legal.

```
if (decision == "yes")
```

Here, "yes" is a string literal which evaluates to a pointer to its first character. This compares 'decision' to a pointer for equivalence. If it were legal, it would be true if they both pointed to the same place, which is not what you want. In fact, if you do this:

```
if ("yes" == "yes")
```

The behavior is undefined. They will both point to the same place if the implementation collapses identical string literals to the same memory location, which it may or may not do. So that's *definitely* not what you want.

```
if (sizeof (decision > 2))
```

I assume you meant:

```
if( sizeof(decision) > 2 )
```

The 'sizeof' operator evaluates at compile time, not run time. And it's independent of what's stored. The sizeof decision is 3 because you defined it to hold three characters. So this doesn't test anything useful.

As mentioned in the other answer, C has the 'strcmp' operator to compare two strings. You could also write your own code to compare them character by character if you wanted to. C++ has much better ways to do this, including string classes.

Here's an example of how you might do that:

```
int StringCompare(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{ // returns 0 if the strings are equivalent, 1 if they're not
  while( (*s1!=0) && (*s2!=0) )
  { // loop until either string runs out
     if(*s1!=*s2) return 1; // check if they match
     s1++; // skip to next character
     s2++;
  }
  if( (*s1==0) && (*s2==0) ) // did both strings run out at the same length?
      return 0;
  return 1; // one is longer than the other
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp(decision, "yes") == 0)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: And you char array should be 4 in size to fit in the null terminating value - forgive me for not explaining enough im writing through the iphone

Comment: That's ok Daniel, I literally just changed my code to if (strcmp(decision, "yes") == 0) and it worked, then I read your answer so thank you.  So I assume by your answer that all C strings terminate in binary 0?

Answer (score 2):

To compare you could use `strcmp` like this:

```
if(strcmp(decision, "yes") == 0) {
    // decision is equal to 'yes'
}
```

Also you should change `char decision[3]` into `char decision[4]` so that the buffer has 
room for a terminating null character.

```
char decision[4] = {0}; // initialize to 0
```

Comment: A note to the OP, you can initialize all elements in an array to 0 by just `char decision[4] = {0}` (even though you don't need to when using most C functions such as `scanf` or `fgets`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok a few things:

- `decision` needs to be an array of 4 `char`s in order to fit the string "yes" in it. That's because in C, the end of a *string* is indicated by the NUL `char` (`'\0'`). So your `char` array will look like: `{ 'y', 'e', 's', '\0' }`.
- *Strings* are compared using functions such as `strcmp`, which compare the **contents** of the string (`char` array), and not the **location**/pointer. A return value of 0 indicates that the two strings match.
- With: `scanf("%s", &decision);`, you don't need to use the address-of operator, the label of an array *is the address of the start of the array*.
- You use `strlen` to get the length of a string, which will just increment a counter until it reaches the NUL `char`, `'\0'`. You *don't* use `sizeof` to check the length of strings, it's a compile-time operation which will return the value `3 * sizeof(char)` for a `char[3]`.
- `scanf` is **unsafe** to use with strings, you should alternatively use `fgets(stdin...)`, or include a width specifier in the format string (such as `"3%s"`) in order to prevent overflowing your buffer. **Note** that if you use `fgets`, take into account it'll store the newline `char` `'\n'` if it reads a whole line of text.

Answer (score 2):

You should be especially careful with null-terminated string in C programming. It is not object. It is a pointer to a memory address. So you can't compare **content** of decision directly with a constant string "yes" which is at another address. Use strcmp() instead.

And be careful that "yes" is actually "yes\0" which will take 4 bytes and the "\0" is very important to strcmp() which will be recognized as the termination during the comparison loop.

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues here:

- You haven't allocated enough storage for the answer:

  ```
  char[3] decision;
  ```

  C strings are bytes in the string followed by an ASCII `NUL` byte: 0x00, `\0`. You have only allocated enough space for `ye\0` at this point. (Well, `scanf(3)` will give you `yes\0` and place that `NUL` in unrelated memory. C can be cruel.) Amend that to include space for the terminating `\0` *and* amend your `scanf(3)` call to prevent the buffer overflow:

  char[4] decision;
     /* ... */
     scanf("%3s", decision);

  (I've left off the `&`, because simply giving the name of the array is the same as giving the address of its first element. It doesn't matter, but I believe this is more idiomatic.)
- C strings cannot be compared with `==`. Use `strcmp(3)` or `strncmp(3)` or `strcasecmp(3)` or `strncasecmp(3)` to compare your strings:

  ```
  if(strcasecmp(decision, "yes") == 0) {
      /* yes */
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

C has lots of lib functions to handle this but it pays to know what you are declaring.

Declaring

```
 char[3] decision;
```

is actually declaring a char array of length 3.  So therefor attempting a comparison of

```
 if(decision == "yes")
```

is comparing a literal against and array and therefor will not work.  Since there is no defined string type in C you have to use pointers, but not directly, if you don't want to.  In C strings are in fact arrays of char so you can declare them both ways eg:

```
char[3] decision ;
* char decision ;
```

Both will in point of fact work but you in the first instance the compiler will allocate the memory for you, but it will ONLY allocate 3 bytes.  Now since strings in C are null terminated you need to actually allocate 4 bytes since you need room for "yes" and the null.  Declaring it the second way simply declares a pointer to **someplace** in memory but you have no idea really where.  You would then have to allocate memory to contain whatever you are going to put there since to do otherwise will more then likely cause a SEGFAULT.

To compare what you get from input you have two options, either use the strcomp() function or do it yourself by iterating through **decision** and comparing each individual byte against "Y" and "E" and "S" until you hit null aka \0.

There are variations on strcomp() to deal with uppercase and lowercase and they are part of the standard string.h library.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  I ended up using if (strcmp("yes") == 0) which works fine.